# What does θ(1) means in this equation?

Tags: asymptotics, recursion

Hello I am trying to understand this recurrence equation with no success.

$ T(n) = T(n / 2) + θ(1)$

```
Base case : $T(1) = θ(1)$

and the solution is $θ(log_2 n)$.
```

What does $θ(1)$ stand for and why is the solution  $θ(log_2 n)$?

Comment: it says that it is a constant

Comment: it stands for constant time in computational complexity. Basically an if your f(n) function's time is T(n)  = O(1) it means no matter how big your n is, it will take the same amount of time to complete. For example, Accessing a specific byte of a bitearray of n size

Comment: ok why is the solution θ(log2 n) ? ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So θ$(1)$ is a constant amount of time. Let's rename it as $k$ for simplicity's sake.

```
T(1) = k
T(2) = T(2 / 2) + k = T(1) + k = 2k
T(4) = T(4 / 2) + k = T(2) + k = 3k
T(8) = T(8 / 2) + k = T(4) + k = 4k
...
T(2^q) = T(2^ q-1) + k = q*k
```

So let's now say $ n = 2^q $ (which equals to $q = log2(n)$), then we have:

```
T(n) = log2(n) * k = log2(n) * θ(1) = θ(log(n))
```